# Asp.Net Web App Hang with comet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implement comet.when client request to server,that request wait to server till the new message arrives.when new message arrives it get back to client.after completion of responce processing client request to server again and wait for new message.

This is working fine for upto 10 request wait at server but then after server can't responce of new request and site getting hanged and have to recycle the application pool.I found the state of all request is ExecuteRequestHandler in workerprocess of IIS.

Please tell me what should i do??

Comment: There really isn't enough information given here to help you. If you can add some code, or let us know what you've done to narrow down the problem, flag your question for moderator review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace your comet implementation with http://www.asp.net/signalr. It will handle any sending/receiving messages originating from either the server or the client in an asynchronous manner. It was also built to scale out

Comment: but we can't able to use this(websocket) in IE 7.0,IE 8.0 and lower version of firefox. can u give me the solution for this??

Comment: signalr works in older browswers by fallbacking to other techniques and technologies websockets it isn't